# Who is 0x093a0ed738b65ed34f2a37a2d44c5e3cd0d0dd45?

Tags: parity, security, kovan

I was working with ethereum using:
- solcjs

- web3
- truffle
- public no firewall kovan node (parity)
- and MultiSigWallet.sol from https://github.com/gnosis/MultiSigWallet

And when I checked my wallet in the kovan node, the balance has been transferred to `0x093a0ed738b65ed34f2a37a2d44c5e3cd0d0dd45` on this transaction https://kovan.etherscan.io/tx/0xf33a3a43b7a13dae0d5d83027ec642a6fd383eafe3d0c5f5c6cedb3580ddb59a?

The transfer happened pretty much when I do a curl call to `personal_unlockAccount`.
Does this transfer because I unlock my account? and there is someone who scanned and auto transfer to `0x093a0ed738b65ed34f2a37a2d44c5e3cd0d0dd45`? The wallet seems to have a lot of KETH on the wallet.

Or this might happen because of the third-party tools I'm using mentioned above?

Comment: According to etherscan, it's an externally-owned account (i.e., not a contract account), to which you have sent 0.000011877202619047 Ether (11,877.202619047 Gwei).

Comment: Just open the transaction link provided in your question, and then click `Click to see more`. You'll see that exactly 21000 gas units were spent, which means that this transaction is ether-transfer to an externally-owned account.

Comment: To answer your other question - it depends on where you send the `curl` to. If it happens pretty much after you do that curl, then it makes sense that it's either the entity on the other side who's making use of your credentials, or perhaps your own script does that (I'm assuming here that you haven't wrote it yourself).

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm afraid, the script that I didn't write myself, and I listed them all on my question. and they seemed to be fine..

Comment: Hang on a second - `public no firewall kovan node`??? Does it actually make any sense to you to unlock your personal account on a public node???

Comment: A word of advice: test ALL your contract AND runtime scripts (deployment, operational past deployment, etc) on a private network first (Truffle & Ganache would be my first choice here). Then, carry on to conducting those tests on a public testnet (as you're trying to do here).

Comment: Yes, I made that node only for testing. So when I unlock an account on a public mode, anyone can do anything to the account wallets in that node without any password?

Comment: I thought, even if I unlock the account, anyone still need to insert a password to sign transaction. But that's not the case... a valuable lesson learned.

Comment: I'm not really sure. I mean, most public nodes (infura for example) probably don't even allow the `personal_unlockAccount` command.

Comment: that `personal_unlockAccount` should be removed from ethereum or parity.

Comment: are you using some opensource explorer?? the same happened to me with this same account. This person has some inbuilt mechanism which does that.

Comment: no I didn't use that...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this recently, too. This same address kept draining my account balance and I thought they must have gained access to my server because I was sure I'd closed down the firewall. Problem for me was that I hadn't realized that I still had my firewall open on the RPC port, and the easy fix was to close that port :).

This is just for anyone else who might come across this on google.